# Accessing an MVC method with a Windows Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security, windows-services

I have a windows service which accesses a function in an MVC application to do some work.

The only way I was able to allow the service to access the function was by granting anonymous access to the function like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFile(ImportedFileModel uploadedFile)
{ 

}
```

I wonder, is there any safer way to do this. I am not convinced that [AllowAnonymous] is a good solution.

Is there anyway I can make the access specific to the Windows Service?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose your function as an web method. If upgrade is an option, you can upgrade your application to ASP.NET MVC 4 and use build in Web API framework.

There are a lot of ways how to manage access to your web methods. Check out for example OAuth.

Good luck!